# How can I accurately seek an AVC MPEG-TS stream in FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, mpeg

I have several video recordings from Full HD IPTV channels that I stored using VLC. These stream dumps are stored as MPEG-TS files and contain AVC-encoded video with MPEG audio.

I would like to extract specific clips from these recordings, based on frame-accurate cutpoints. However, I'm having a difficult time determining the exact, millisecond timestamps I need to pass to *FFMPEG*'s `-ss` and `-to` parameters to hit the cutpoints I want precisely. Here is what I have tried so far:

### Attempt 1

My initial try was to load the `.ts` files into *Avidemux* since it allows comfortable frame-by-frame seeking, and displays the timestamp of the current frame in the necessary precision. However, if I put the timestamp of a frame I seeked to (in format `HH:MM:SS.mmm`) into the *FFMPEG* parameters, the cut will actually be off by several frames, sometimes over a second. The drift is different for each file, and can be positive or negative.

Then I noticed that for most of these recordings, for the first frame *Avidemux* actually shows a timestamp that isn't zero (e.g. `00:00:00.280` or even `00:00:00.216`). I assumed that *VLC* starts the recording immediately, but *Avidemux* ignores everything until the first I-frame. I still wonder at a timestamp like `00:00:00.216`, though, because these videos are at 25 fps and 216 is not even a multiple of 40 ms.

[image]

### Attempt 2

I tried a two-pass process, in which I would encode the video once with starting the encode slightly earlier than the cut I want, and finishing it slightly after the end I want. I would then use *Avidemux* to count the superfluous frames in the beginning and end of the video, and move the cut points by `nFrames * 40 ms` inwards. However, the results were *still* not precise, it would lead me to sometimes shorten the video by too few frames, sometimes too many.

Losing trust in *Avidemux*'s timestamp accuracy, or at least concluding that it does some calculations differently than *FFMPEG*, I thought the safest way would be to use the same tool for determining the cut points that I also use to actually cut the video.

### Attempt 3

I tried to extract single frames around the desired cutting points using FFMPEG, by using the same `-ss` and `-to` parameters I use to cut the video, but selecting only a range closely around the desired cutting points, and writing the frames to picture files. I would also use a filter to burn in each frame's exact timestamp, as determined by *FFMPEG*, directly into the picture. That way I could just read off the desired cutting points and use them for the actual encode. My command line would look something like this:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.ts -ss 00:00:29.000 -to 00:00:31.000 -vf drawtext=fontfile=roboto.ttf:fontsize=40:text='%{pts\:hms}':fontcolor=white@0.75:x=10:y=10 image%03d.png
```

I would then find the exact PNG I want the cut to be at, look at the timestamp, and if it said `00:00:30.160`, that would be the timestamp I'd use for the `-ss` of the actual cut.

[image]

However, this *still* didn't work and my cutting points are still several frames earlier or later than the extracted PNGs. So changing *FFMPEG*'s output from video to images seems to affect how timestamps are calculated, because they don't match up!

---

So far I have not found a way to avoid having to do a lengthy binary search process to manually approach the exact timestamps the cuts need to be at, which is especially cumbersome because I can only get the timestamps I need by doing "full-decode seeks" (i.e. using `-ss` after the input parameter, not before) and it can take a long time to seek to a position several hours into a recording.

How can I find the timestamp I need to get a frame-exact cut from *FFMPEG* in an MPEG Transport Stream, without having to decode, cut, and save the video segments multiple times in order to manually inch my way towards them?

Here is the *MediaInfo* on one of the recordings, in case it contains any clues about something being weird with the streams themselves:

```
General
ID                                       : 1 (0x1)
Complete name                            : C:\Users\…\vlc-record-2021-03-09-00h23m11s.ts
Format                                   : MPEG-TS
File size                                : 2.31 GiB
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable

Video
ID                                       : 256 (0x100)
Menu ID                                  : 1 (0x1)
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : 27
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS
Standard                                 : Component
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Interlaced
Scan type, store method                  : Separated fields
Scan order                               : Top Field First
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709

Audio
ID                                       : 257 (0x101)
Menu ID                                  : 1 (0x1)
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1
Format profile                           : Layer 2
Codec ID                                 : 3
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Delay relative to video                  : -248 ms

Menu
ID                                       : 4096 (0x1000)
Menu ID                                  : 1 (0x1)
List                                     : 256 (0x100) (AVC) / 257 (0x101) (MPEG Audio)
Service name                             : Service01
Service provider                         : FFmpeg
Service type                             : digital television
```

**Additional info:** The timestamp drift is different for each file, but constant within each file. That is, if I need to do several cuts in a video, and for one cut determine that the timestamp given in the pictures extracted with *FFMPEG* is always 160ms lower than what I need to use for `-ss`, I can use that same offset for the rest of the cuts in the same file, and it will be precise.

Comment: What's the command you use to extract a clip?  Is your designated start point a keyframe?

Comment: I actually also encode in addition to cutting, and my cut points are not usually keyframes. That's why I do full-decode seeks, which is one reason the process is so slow, sometimes I have to seek hours into a file. However, I found that the inaccuracy is the same regardless of whether I encode or just cut with `-c:v copy`, just that the latter will be garbled in the beginning.

A typical command I use to encode the snippets would look like this: `ffmpeg.exe -i in.ts -c:v libx265 -crf 25 -vf yadif -c:a copy -ss 00:15:00.000 -to 00:45:00.000 out.mkv`

Comment: Your extraction command deinterlaces the video but the drawtext cmd doesn't. You should use the same filters in both.